# What does 'fully determines' mean in the context of postgres functional dependency statistics?

Tags: postgresql

I am following the example of how to use 'create statistics' in postgresql from [this page](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/03/06/postgres-planner-and-its-usage-of-statistics/).

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
                     col1 int,
                     col2 int
);

INSERT INTO tbl SELECT i/10000, i/100000
FROM generate_series (1,10000000) s(i);

CREATE STATISTICS s1 (dependencies) on col1, col2 from tbl;
ANALYZE tbl;

SELECT stxname, stxkeys, stxdependencies
FROM pg_statistic_ext
WHERE stxname = 's1';
```

returns:

```
stxname,stxkeys,stxdependencies
s1,1 2,{"1 => 2": 1.000000}
```

However, I'm confused by this line

> Looking at this, we can see that Postgres realizes that col1 fully
>   determines col2 and therefore has a coefficient of 1 to capture that
>   information.

In the example there are many records in col2 that are repeated. So how does col1 'fully determine' col2? What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that if `col1` is identical for two rows, then `col2` will also be identical.

In other words, if the functional dependency were perfect, you could remove `col2` from the table and use a lookup table that maps `col1` to `col2`. But don't forget that these are only statistical data from a sample of the rows, so even if you see a dependency of 1 in the extended statistics, that is no proof that it is really always so (only very often).